# Am getting this error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting this error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

```
plaintext= input("Enter the plaintext:")
length = len(plaintext)
print ("The length is:", length)
for i in range(0,(len(plaintext)-1)
    E[i]= (15*plaintext[i]+20)%26;
    print (E[i])
```

Comment: Could you provide the full trackback... I reckon you should get an error for the missing `):` before anything :) (which kind of makes me wonder if that's the *actual code* that's being run...)

Answer (score 2):

`plaintext` is a string, so does `plaintext[i]`. `15*plaintext[i]` multiplies the string, and you are trying to add an integer to a string with `+20`. so just:

```
15*int(plaintext[i])+20 #if plaintext is a string of decimals, don't know what exactly you want
```

or I guess you're doing something like encryption, that way you need to convert a single char to integer using [**ord**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and convert back with it's inverse **[chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr)** :

```
In [4]: text='abcd'
   ...: for ch in text:
   ...:     print(chr((15*(ord(ch)-97)+20)%26+97), sep='', end='')
ujyn
```

Comment: Exactly I need to get the plaintext from the user, which I need to encrypt and then i need to convert to decimal before involving it in the equation "E(x) = (15x + 20) MOD 26", where x is the plain text. And the above equation should be applied character by character. Finally again i need to convert back to string. how to convert the input (plaintext) to decimal starting from A=0 to Z=25. And taking each character from the plain text and applying that equation and then finally converting the resultant interger again back to the string.

Comment: @AndrewNiteesh, how to? I've already shown you: `ord(ch)-97`. Besides, it's better to post the exact question (formulas, sample input and output) like this comment when you ask next time ;)

Comment: import sys
plaintext= input("Enter the plaintext:")
length = len(plaintext)
print ("The length is:", length)
for i in range(0, len(plaintext)):
    c = chr((15*(ord(plaintext)-97)+20)%26+97)
    print (c)

For the above code, in the output, am getting an error like this:
  
Enter the plaintext:andrew
The length is: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\affinecipher.py", line 6, in <module>
    c = chr((15*(ord(plaintext)-97)+20)%26+97)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found

Comment: @AndrewNiteesh ***please*** notice my `ch` is a **single character** which iterates through the text. You can `ord('a')`, but not `ord('abc')`

Answer (score 2):

`plaintext` is a `str`, so `plaintext[i]` is a string as well (one character).  Multiply it by 15 and you again have a `str` (15 characters).  If you try to add a `20` to that, the interpreter assumes that you want to convert that `20` to a `str` and append it to the existing `str`.  But it does not do that implicit conversion from `int` to `str`, and it's telling you that.

You might want to use sth like

```
(15 * (ord(plaintext[i]) - ord('A')) + 20) % 26
```

Your question isn't clear about your true intentions, so we have to guess.

Comment: I need to get the plaintext from the user, which I need to encrypt and then i need to convert to decimal before involving it in the equation "E(x) = (15x + 20) MOD 26", where x is the plain text. And the above equation should be applied character by character. Finally again i need to convert back to string. how to convert the input (plaintext) to decimal starting from A=0 to Z=25. And taking each character from the plain text and applying that equation and then finally converting the resultant interger again back to the string. Pls help me out with this.

Comment: I changed my answer according to your new specification.  It does not contain any checks for the input to contain _only_ letters from _A_ to _Z_, though.